# Can not load PostgreSQL driver when reinstall php on mac (El Capitan)

Tags: php, macos

The first time I install php7, every thing work well:

```
brew install php70
brew install php70-pdo-pgsql
```

But when I remove it, install php56, remove php56 and reinstall php70 then I got errors:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/opt/php70-pdo-pgsql/pdo_pgsql.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php70-pdo-pgsql/pdo_pgsql.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/opt/php70-pthreads/pthreads.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php70-pthreads/pthreads.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer.
We just remove and reinstall these extensions from source.

```
brew unlink php70-pdo-pgsql
brew unlink php70-pthreads
brew reinstall php70-pdo-pgsql --build-from-source
brew reinstall php70-pthreads --build-from-source
```